# Python Turtle graphics box doesn't show up

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is my code and when I run this code:

```
from turtle import Turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")


    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
```

nothing happens, just the shell appears saying RESTART like you can see in pictures.  Help me please!

[image: error description]

Answer (score 0):

Please write down the code instead of linking a screenshot. Makes things easier :)

The code is inside a function definition but you didn't call the function anywhere. Try to call it at the end of your program:

```
from turtle import Turtle

def draw_square(): # function definition
    window = turtle.Screen()
    ...
    ...
    brad.right(90)

draw_square() # call the function
```

Comment: umm thank you for the help but what should i do in order to complete a square ? like i just don,t know what i am missing right now...:(

Comment: @HamzaSajid you say that the square is not "complete", can you describe what shape is being drawn? Edit your initial question with more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with your `import` code:

```
from turtle import Turtle
```

it is inconsistent with your usage:

```
window = turtle.Screen()
brad = turtle.Turtle()
```

Since you only imported `Turtle` from turtle, neither of these lines will work.  You can do either:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
brad = turtle.Turtle()
```

or (preferably if you want to only use the object-oriented turtle):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

window = Screen()
brad = Turtle()
```

The next problem with your `import` is that it's not consistent with the `import` cited in the Python Shell error message:

```
     import Turtle
ImportError: No module named Turtle
```

which might mean the code you're looking at and the code you're running aren't the same.  Now let's try to put together a consistent, complete (Python 2, I'm assuming) program from your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

def draw_square(turtle):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

brad = Turtle()
brad.shape("turtle")
brad.color("yellow")
brad.speed(2)

draw_square(brad)

mainloop()
```